# Strange traceroute on home network

Tags: router, ping, traceroute

In our home network (with a central AVM FritzBox as an internet router and central switch) connection gets lost from time to time to some of the devices. If lost, no ping is possible any more and after reconnecting the carrier everything works well for some minutes.

Casting a traceroute (from a linux machine) on such an ip address getting lost later shows the following strange behavoir:

- First traceroute shows one hop and reaches it's destination
- second traceroute shows one hop, some lost packages, but reaches it's destination
- third traceroute shows six hops, but does also reach the device
- fourth traceroute shows more than 30 hops and never reaches the device (due to the hop limit of course).

After some retries the device cannot be reached at all.

Pinging a connected device with ping instead of traceroute, that has not gone away, does not show any packasges getting lost.

This behaviour can be reproduced even if only the machine with the ping and the destination device are on-line.

Can someone guess the reason?